# AFNetworking via RestKit - files missing

Tags: cocoapods, afnetworking, restkit

I've installed RestKit via CocoaPods this afternoon. I immediately had duplicate/redefinition errors because I already had manually imported AFNetworking before, and CocoaPods re-installed it.

So I deleted the manually installed version, but now I am getting missing files errors, because apparently CocoaPods didn't install all the files.

```
AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager.m:29:9: 'AFURLSessionManager.h' file not found

RKHTTPRequestOperation.h:21:9: 'AFHTTPClient.h' file not found
```

These files are not in the AFNetworking folder in my Pods folder.

I've tried removing RestKit from my Podfile and doing a clean install, but nothing is working.

These are the relevant lines in the Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '8.1'
  pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.24.0'
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to RestKit 0.27, which has incorporated AFNetworking 1.3 with non-conflicting names for its own use. Then if you need AFNetworking for your own code, you can add it as a separate Cocoapod.